# Python - Using Recursion to find the sum of Max and Min in a nested list

Tags: python, recursion

Here's everything I got so far...
I can't figure what I have done wrong

First my helper function

```
def max_min(l):

    if isinstance (l[0], list):
        result = max_min(l[0])

    elif len(l) == 2:
        if l[0] < l[1]:
            result = l[0], l[1]
        else:
            result = l[1], l[0]

    else:
        Min, Max = max_min(l[1:])
        if l[0] <= Min:
            result = l[0], Max
        elif l[0] >= Max:
            result = Min, l[0]
        else:
            result = Min, Max

    return result
```

When tried to do this

```
l = [6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 2, [3, 2], 1]
print max_min(l)
```

It gives me `(2, 7)` which i expected to be `(1, 7)`

I'm out of ideas... anyone can point me out the directions?

Comment: is using recursion critical to the application? would be much simpler to convert it to a single list then sort it and take the first and last elements

Comment: Run your code through a debugger and see where it doesn't behave like you expect.

Comment: Is this homework? There's no reason to do this in real code.

Comment: Yea this is homework... well exercise~ We are not allow to go through the list more than once

Comment: @user984343. In that case, this is XY problem. There are much better options than recursion. However, points for trying and almost succeeding on your own.

Answer (score 4):

The moment your program reaches a nested list, it stops evaluating the other elements. The block `if isinstance (l[0], list)` ensures that if there is a nested list, the remaining elements are not evaluated since `Min, Max = max_min(l[1:])` is never called.

You can fix the `if` block with something like this:

```
if isinstance (l[0], list):
    Nested_Min, Nested_Max = max_min(l[0])
    Remainder_Min, Remainder_Max = max_min(l[1:])
    Min = Nested_Min if Nested_Min < Remainder_Min else Remainder_Min
    Max = Nested_Max if Nested_Max > Remainder_Max else Remainder_Max
    result = Min, Max
```

You should also replace the check for `if len(l) == 2` with:

```
if len(l) == 1:
    result = l[0], l[0]
```

That way your function will not fail for single-element lists. Finally, add something like the following at the beginning:

```
if not l:
    return ()
```

Comment: @user984343. In that case, perhaps selecting this answer would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
def min_max(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        t = [min_max(v) for v in l]
        return min([m[0] for m in t]), max([m[1] for m in t])
    else:
        return l, l
```

Sample output:

```
>>> l = [6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 2, [3, 2], 1]
>>> min_max(l)
(1, 7)
>>>
```

Note that an empty list or sub-list will cause an error, so you might need to add a check for that if you care about it.

Comment: If the OP was going to use `min` or `max` he/she could just apply that to the original list

Comment: Neat solution. You may want to ask the OP if using `min` and `max` is allowed. Given the weird recursion constraints, I doubt it is.

Comment: @sedavidw. That is absolutely not true. Those functions would barf on a nested list.

Comment: @sedavidw No, because the list can contain nested lists.  That's the whole point.  Please read the post again.

Comment: You're not answering OP's question.

Comment: @sedavidw: `TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()`. I am not sure what part of that "works just fine".

Comment: I retract my previous comments, they were in fact incorrect

Comment: @sedavidw You are wrong.  Try this:  `min([2, [1, 3]])`.  That gives `2` rather than `1`.

Comment: OK. Works in Py2, but answer is not correct. Not even sure how it compares list to int.

Comment: @Mad Physicist  All it's doing is comparing integers to lists, the same as the ordinary comparison operators do, which isn't the desired behavior.  Python 2 doesn't give an error, but Python 3 does.

Comment: @TomKarzes. I realize it's comparing integers to lists, but how?

Comment: @Mad Physicist As far as I can tell, in Python 2 any integer compares as less than any list.

Comment: @TomKarzes. You are absolutely correct. And the reason is messed up. It's because lexicographically, 'int' < 'list'. Not kidding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/2988730

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment you would still need to use recursion to flatten the list as you have a mix of integers and lists, the code would look as follows:

```
def flatten(l):
    tmp = []
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, int):
            tmp.append(i)
        elif isinstance(i, list):
            tmp += flatten(i)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("found unexpected type {t}".format(t=type(i)))
    return tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function can be simplified and improved at the same time. See the following for details:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


def main():
    array = [6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 2, [3, 2], 1]
    print(sum_min_max(array))


def sum_min_max(array):
    return (lambda a, b: a + b)(*get_min_max(array))


def get_min_max(array, minimum=+float('inf'), maximum=-float('inf')):
    if array:
        head, *tail = array
        if isinstance(head, (list, tuple)):
            minimum, maximum = get_min_max(head, minimum, maximum)
        else:
            if head < minimum:
                minimum = head
            if head > maximum:
                maximum = head
        minimum, maximum = get_min_max(tail, minimum, maximum)
    return minimum, maximum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```